# Creating aggregator instance for each datastore

Tags: spring-integration

Is it possible to have an instance of the spring aggregator for each new unique correlation id? A MessageStore gets created for each unique correlation id but I was wondering if it was also possible to have a 1:1 instance for aggregator:MessageStore.

I want to have instance values in the aggregator class based on what I extracted from the incoming message that helps me determine the release strategy per MessageStore.

UPDATED: Terminology corrected.

Comment: `>A unique datastore gets created for each unique correlation id` - that is not correct; please explain your issue in more detail.

Comment: In the annotated aggregator java class.The @ReleaseStrategy, a unique list correlated to the correlation id is passed in. I equated the correlated list entry on the method signature to a unique datastore per list. So I am assuming all list entries are kept in the same (in this default) in memory datastore.  The main question remain the same if it's possible to have a aggregator instance per unique correlation id.  Does that make more sense?I will update if it does.

Comment: Thanks, although the terminology is wrong, it helped me understand what you are getting at). See my answer.

Comment: sorry about that. I had  `datastore` hard wired in my head when yes I should of typed MessageGroup and MessageGroupStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a separate "datastore" for each correlationId.

The aggregator uses a `MessageGroupStore` which is in-memory by default but can be one of a number of persistent `MessageGroupStores`.

Each correlationId gets a new `MessageGroup` which is stored in the `MessageGroupStore`.

You cannot have a new instance of the POJO aggregator class for each group; if you have state you need to manage you would need to use a `Map` keyed by the correlation strategy to hold that state rather than simple fields.

It is guaranteed that only one thread will ever call your POJO concurrently for a particular group.

You may need to change your release strategy to take a `List<Message<?>>` so you can determine the group id (usually correlationId, but can be anything created by your correlation strategy).

Comment: Using a list string is fine in my scenario. My main issue stem`s from the fact I determine the release strategy by extracting the correlation id from the incoming message ( xml tag value ) and that value is used to point to a directory file system location that has the expected number of messages. 1 per file. For 2 different concurrent MessageStores that expected number of messages that determine the release can be different. I was just looking to see if I could avoid unmarshelling the message every time and only do it once per MessageStore. Thanks for the answer.